# Fancybox title at the top

Tags: jquery, fancybox

So, I want to position the "title" of fancybox at the top, instead of the bottom without losing any functionality.

It shouldn't be "over" the picture at the top, but rather push the picture down and show the title text there. ( as it would at the bottom )

How can I do that with Fancybox 1.4 or 2 ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the fancybox stylesheet (jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css file), adjust the padding for #fancybox-content:

```
#fancybox-content {
    padding: 45px 0 0 0;
}
```

The 45px will allow room for your title.

Then, make sure that your title position is set in your config to `over`:

```
'titlePosition': 'over',
```

Finally, add this option:

```
'onComplete': function() {
    $("#fancybox-title").css({'top':'0px', 'bottom':'auto'});
}
```